# How do I store a new entry in Rails when a button is clicked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in one of my models that, when called, fetches a tweet using the twitter gem and stores some parts of it. I'd like to be able to trigger that action from the web interface to my app. What is the Rails Way to accomplish this? I've seen some references to not calling model methods from views, so should I be doing this from within a controller somehow instead?

My method (the relevant models are Sponsor and Sponsortweet (so my model name wouldn't conflict with Tweet, from the gem):

```
def create_tweet                                                                  
    tweet = Twitter.user_timeline(self.twitter).first                               
    self.sponsortweets.create!(content: tweet.text,                                 
                               tweet_id: tweet.id,                                  
                               tweet_created_at: tweet.created_at,                  
                               profile_image_url: tweet.user.profile_image_url,     
                               from_user: tweet.from_user,)                         
end
```

EDIT:

I created a `tweet` method in my sponsors controller:

```
def tweet
  @sponsor = Sponsor.find(params[:id])
  @sponsor.create_tweet
end
```

and added the following to my config/routes.rb: `match 'tweet', to: 'sponsors#tweet', via: :post`.

As well as the following code in my view (I'm using haml):

`= button_to :tweet, tweet_path(@sponsor)`

However, clicking the button results in the following error:

`Couldn't find Sponsor without an ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should have a button that posts to a specific route in your controller. That controller would then call the method in your model. Having no idea what your app actually looks like, here's an example:

**EDIT** includes better example

View (assuming it's a Sponsor view):

```
<%= button_to :submit, tweet_path %>
```

Controller:

```
def tweet
    Sponsor.create_tweet
end
```

And your model would stay the same, except you'd change your method to a class method like so:

```
def self.create_tweet
    ...your code here...
end
```

Since it seems this isn't tied to any particular sponsor, you'll use a class method and thus don't need an instance of the class to call your method. That said, it seems like you would want an instance of your class at some point...

Comment: Ok, I think that makes sense. Are you saying that this would post to the tweet method in my sponsors controller? If so, would I need to e.g. associate the tweet_path route with sponsors#tweet?

Comment: Yep, exactly. If you want a more specific example please post the relevant model, view and controller

Comment: Can you help me understand button_to better? That code generates an input with value="tweet". Is that what it should be? Clicking on that button results in this error: `Couldn't find Sponsor without an ID`

Comment: I should also mention this is what I put in my config/routes.rb: `match 'tweet', to: 'sponsors#tweet', via: :post`

Comment: Edit your question and post your code and I can provide more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be curious to hear other people's answers, as I'm now wondering if there is such a way to bypass the controller all-together.

However, my take on this is that, since Rails is an MVC (Model View Controller) framework, I think the Rails way of accomplishing what you're considering is probably to simply handle the action normally; through the **controller** to the **model**.

If I am correct in assuming you have a button or link, or perhaps some AJAX, which is initiating the server-side Twitter processing, then I would set up your routing for that URL to point to a controller action method, which would then call your model method `myModel.create_tweet`.